# selecting a value from a ListPicker in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

can any one please explain a simple way to select a value from a listpicker control and under what event its best to select the value, apart from SelectionChanged event in windows phone 8 ?

Comment: As far as I know there's only this way. Why don't you want to use the `SelectionChanged` event?

Comment: ohk thanks but i need a way to know get the values and indexes from the listpicker controler

Answer (score 0):

For that you could do something like this:

Assume this is your `ListPicker` in your `xaml`:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding name}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding name}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

Then in your code:

```
var filterdata = e.Result;
var filtervalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<filterdatas>>(filterdata);//filterdatas is just the name of the list which you're displaying 
filterpicker.ItemsSource = filtervalue;
```

Within your `SelectionChanged` event handler, you could something like this to get the values:

```
if(filterpicker.SelectedItem == null) //here filterpicker is the name of the `ListPicker`
return;
filterdatas element = filterpicker.SelectedItem as filterdatas;
MessageBox.Show("This is the id:"+element.id);//here the id of the selected item is being retrieved
```

For more you could refer here:

[How to Get the Selected Item of a ListPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591841/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code in my Project and it works great.

```
strListPickerValue = ((ListPickerItem)lpRemind.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

here lpRemind is the listPicket.